# Using Interrupted Time Series for understanding impact of a treatment

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, python, inference, hydrology

I am trying to use interrupted time series analysis to figure out the impact of a groundwater recovery program on Well Depth initiated on March 1st. I am trying to understand the difference between using the actual well depth as the dependent variable and using the change in well depth as the dependent variable (which I should mention gives the result that makes more sense). The dataset has 2 data points per day from December to April. My code for the first regression:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

df['x'] = np.arange(len(df)) + 1
df['xt'] = np.concatenate((np.zeros(len(df[df["t"]==0])), 1+np.arange(len(df[df["t"]==1]))))

model = ols("Well_Depth_to_Water ~ x + t + xt", data=df)
results1 = model.fit()
results1.summary()
```

[image: Results1]

This shows that the treatment had a positive impact on groundwater. However, when I use Change in Well Depth as the dependent variable I get that the treatment had a negative impact.

```
df["Change"] = df["Well_Depth_to_Water"]  - df["Well_Depth_to_Water"].shift(1)

model = ols("Change ~ x + t + xt", data=df)
results2 = model.fit()
results2.summary()
```

[image]

Seeing this discrepancy, I plotted the predictions versus the actual values getting the following plots:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df["datetime"], df["Well_Depth_to_Water"])
ax.plot(df["datetime"], results1.predict(), linestyle="--")
fig.autofmt_xdate()
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df["datetime"], df["Change"])
ax.plot(df["datetime"], results2.predict(), linestyle="--")
fig.autofmt_xdate()
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
well_value = df["Well_Depth_to_Water"][1]
predictions = []
for i in results2.predict():
    well_value = well_value + i
    predictions.append(well_value)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df["datetime"], df["Well_Depth_to_Water"])
ax.plot(df["datetime"], predictions, linestyle="--")
fig.autofmt_xdate()
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I am confused why the second regression seems to give better predictions than the first. It seems to me that the first was not able to model the non-linearity of the data as well as the second, but I want to know why that is the case.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this; I would really appreciate your help!